# How to correctly link libraries when compling c++

Tags: c++

I have written a code in c++ that makes use of the wigxjpf-1.9 package for computing some Wigner Symbols. To compile the code I use g++ and I just type

```
g++ file_name.cpp -o my_file -I ~/path_to_file/wigxjpf-1.9/inc/ -I /usr/local/include -L ~/path_to_file/wigxjpf-1.9/lib/ -lwigxjpf -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

and it works.

Now I'm trying to modify it in such a way that it works in parallel. To do it I use openmp. My problem is that when I try to compile the file. I type

```
g++-9 -fopenmp file_name.cpp -o my_file -I ~/path_to_file/wigxjpf-1.9/inc/ -I /usr/local/include -L ~/path_to_file/wigxjpf-1.9/lib/ -lwigxjpf -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

but now the following error appears:

```
ld: library not found for -lgsl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am I typing something wrong?

Please tell me if more details are needed to answer my question.

Comment: Have you installed gsl on your computer?

Comment: See also: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/usage.html

Comment: Yes I have installed it. In fact I already use gsl on the single-thread version of my code.

Comment: Can you build the single-thread version with g++-9? How exactly have you installed that? GCC has supported OpenMP for years: can you try your system g++ with -fopenmp? I'd be surprised if it didn't support it.

Comment: I tried to do what you have suggested. The single-thread version does not compile with g++-9 because of the error that I get in the multi-thread version.

Comment: Then I tried to compile the multi-thread version but the following error appears: clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

Comment: Oh, so your system compiler is LLVM not GCC? Is this a Mac? (Or if this is Linux, which distribution are you using?). I'd guess then that your g++-9 is set to only link static libraries and you only have a dynamic version of libgsl, a .so not an .a, or vice versa; or it's rejecting the libgsl you've provided because it's the wrong number of bits or something else. Do you get any more errors before "library not found" that might be relevant? Is the -L path to libgsl definitely correct, and it's not that the system compiler is finding the library somewhere else?

Comment: D'oh, I'd missed that your -L is for wigxjpf not gsl. I'd guess then that you've installed libgsl in /usr/local, so the library is in /usr/local/lib? And for some reason your system compiler already has /usr/local/lib in its search path but g++-9 doesn't. Try adding a `-L /usr/local/lib` just after `-L ~/path_to_file/wigxjpf-1.9/lib/`.

Comment: Thanks now it works! Yes I have a Mac and I added what you suggested me, and now it compiles.